# BigQuery Percentile Partitioned by Value in Column

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with many entries for many users. I would like to compute the 20th percentile for each user into a separate table.

I have:

| User | Value |
| --- | --- |
| John | 1 |
| John | 14 |
| John | 34 |
| John | 11 |
| Mary | 3 |
| Mary | 5 |
| ... | ... |

And I want to have a table with the 20th percentile for each user like:

| Name | Percentile |
| --- | --- |
| John | xx |
| Mary | yy |

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try below

```
select distinct user, 
  percentile_cont(value, 0.2) over(partition by user) percentile
from your_table
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly! Could I use a CASE WHEN inside the percentile function to only consider positive values of the oclumn?

Comment: you can try just simply add `where value > 0` after ` from your_table`

Comment: Thank you, Sir!

Comment: consider voting up the answer (if not yet) :o)

Comment: I did :) It works when I only select the percentiles, but I think it will not work when I also want to select another column, then it will only select the values of the other column where the "value" used for percentiles is >0. Basically, is there a way to only set the condition >0 inside the select percentile and not for the whole query?

Comment: I recommend you to post new question with all the new details so we will be able to help you further :o)